# What is the time format used in KML files?

Tags: objective-c, xml, timestamp, kml, time-format

I am parsing a KML file on the iPhone, and I need to know what the time format of this string from the KML file is: `2011-05-16T08:00:59Z`.

I think it is somewhere along the lines of the following, but I don't know what the `Z` stands for: `YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/date_and_time_format.htm). The `Z` stands for [Zulu time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time), also called UTC or GMT, i.e. the `+0` timezone.

Comment: Thanks, but what letter do I use, Z? I tried the following, but it doesn't work - `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ`.

Comment: @XcodeDev `Z` is the correct letter to use if the timezone of the time is UTC. If it's not in UTC, the easiest way is just to calculate the equivalent UTC time. Alternatively, you [can add the timeuone offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC). Could you clarify `It doesn't work`? What does your program output currently, and how do you detect that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I use this in Python to convert Django objects into KML TimeStamp (notice the capital S in TimeStamp - that threw me for a while):

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

# Access the Date Time of the created object
dtg = str(loc.created_at)

# Import the Django timestamp (which includes miliseconds)
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(dtg, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00")
# Convert it to UTC Format
datetime_obj_utc = datetime_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))

# Convert it to Zulu time
date_time = datetime_obj_utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

# Build the KML output
output += '  <Placemark><name>Feature</name>\n'
output += '      <TimeStamp><when>'+date_time+'</when></TimeStamp>\n'
...
```